# What are the benefits to declaring a functional class as opposed to declaring a regular class

Tags: javascript, class

I've written a bunch of functional classes following this structure:

```
var One = function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.write = function() {
        console.log("Yes");
    };
    return obj;
}
```

I want a static method in one of my functional class declarations, But I don't the differences/benefits/trade-offs compared to just having written regular class declarations like this for example:

```
class One {
  static write(){
    console.log("Yes");
  }
}
```

I understand both have to be instantiated after declaration.

case a:
`var one = One();`
case b:
`var one = One();`

Aside from that, what are the differences and why use one over the other?

Comment: The `class` declaration syntax is quite new, and it's basically a "syntactic sugar" wrapper around the older way of doing things. It's all really the same.

Comment: why does interpreter not like the i make static methods in the functional class then? for instance, it doesn't like:
`var One = function() {
    var obj = {};
    static write = function() {
        console.log("Yes");
    };
    return obj;
}`

Comment: because the syntax does not allow for `static` in the middle of ordinarly code; it's only allowed in a `class` declaration.

Comment: @Pointy These are not the same - classes are 'syntactic sugar' for prototypal inheritance of methods, but the other version he has here is a pure old-school factory function.

Comment: @JonnyRathbone yes that's true, the question sort-of muddles together constructor stuff with factory functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference here. In your first version, a factory function, a new `write` function is created each time you create a new `One` object. A class's static method however is a method that exists on the class itself, and any instance of the class using it would use the same static method. So this is better for memory and potentially other use cases, theoretically.

Also it may have just been a typo but the factory function is not instantiated, but invoked, like you have written. The class however can be said to have been instantiated, but you use the `new` keyword for this: `var one = new One()` (though if you are only using static methods you might not need this...)

Comment: Another problem is that the call with the class in the question would be `One.write()`, not `one.write()`. The method would need to be non-static.

Comment: Referring to the `class` syntax static method?static method invocation would be on the class, not the variable?